# Поразрядная дизъюнкция машина тьюринга

Tags: массивы, информатика

Как с помощью машины тьюринга вычислить поразрядную дизъюнкцию двух двоичных чисел? Головка стоит справа от чисел. Можно таблицей,можно кодом.